# jQuery acting on condition of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at my fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/rtrz86oe/7/

```
var opened = false;
```

When you click the button, the variable should update to true, which it does. This means the first conditional is working;

```
if (opened == false){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(){
        opened = true;
    });
};
```

Great, but when you click it again, the variable should update to false. As the variable is currently 'true' it should change back to false with this function. But it doesn't.

```
if (opened == true){

    $('.btn').on('click',function(){
        opened = false;
    });
};
```

It seems the second conditional function isn't running for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the condition within the handler itself

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
        if (opened == false) {
            opened = true;
        } else {
            opened = false;
        }
    });
```

**Or**, you can express the same as

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
       opened = !opened;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

you are adding the click handler inside conditionals, instead you should do:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
    opened = !opened; //reverse the state
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var opened = false;
 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
    opened = !opened;
 });

$('.state').text(opened);
$('.check').on('click',function(){
    $('.state').text(opened);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rtrz86oe/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/rtrz86oe/8/

```
var opened = false;

$('.state').text(opened);

$('.check').on('click',function(){

if(opened) {
    opened = false;
} else {
    opened = true;
}
$('.state').text(opened);
});
```